# Clarification regarding a verse in Valmiki Ramayana.?

Tags: ramayana, rama, hanuman, lokas, swarga

How did Lord Hanuman see the abode of Lord Brahma,Indra and other below mentioned Gods in the Himalayas.?

> स ब्रह्मकोशं रजतालयं च | शक्रालयं रुद्रशरप्रमोक्षम् | हयाननं
> ब्रह्मशिरश्च दीप्तं | ददर्श वैवस्वत किङ्करांश् च || ६-७४-५९ ||

[Translation](https://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga74/yuddha_74_frame.htm).:

> **He saw the abode of Brahma** the lord of creation, Kailasa the abode of Shiva the lord of dissolution, the **abode of Indra** the lord of celestials, the arrow-discharging place of Rudra, the worshipping place of Hayagriva, the horse-faced form of Vishnu, the shining place at which Brahma's head fell down, the sun-god and Kimkaras.

How can Brahma Loka and Swarga Loka be on earth ?

Comment: Clearly according to Valimiki,  Brahmaloka, Kailasa and Indraloka are wherever the Himalayas (that Hanuman went to) are. Even celebrated commentators on the Ramayana like Govindaraja have not felt that this verse is special or needing extra explanations. Why do you think these places are not on earth?

Comment: Cause many purana explains that brhama loka and indra loka are on different dimensions.

Comment: (1) What does that mean? 'dimension' is a modern term. Can you cite some examples from those puranas?  (2) It is not uncommon for different scriptures to be inconsistent with each other. This is why we have an order of hierarchy for credibility of scriptures.

Comment: When I read this shlok for first time, I interpreted it as Hanuman flying so high that Brahma lok was visible to him.

Comment: I too thought the same but ... brhama loka is too far from the earth .. vishnu purana mention it ... n we also know that there is 7 lokas above us and 7 loka below us. . So .. m really confused...